# Show element on button click

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to simply hide show an element on button click which loads as hidden. I am trying to use [hidden] attribute  with Angular.

```
<div class="table-responsive" [hidden]="isHidden">
<table class="table">
<thead class="thead-light">
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:center">{{blueFighter}}</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Round</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">{{redFighter}}</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="tablerows">
..Div continues down here

</div>
<button (click)="createCardClick(hide)" class="btn btn-success">Create Scorecard</button>
```

Typescript:

```
createCardClick(hide) {
hide.hidden = !hide.hidden;

}
```

Nothing is really happening so far, not really sure how the hidden attirbute works.

Comment: Where are you setting `isHidden`?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out on my own. I used *ngIf instead.

TS:

```
 showHide: boolean;

 createCardClick() {
this.showHide = !this.showHide;
this.rounds = Array(this.selectedRounds).fill(0).map((x, i) => i);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="table-responsive" *ngIf="showHide">

  <button (click)="createCardClick()" class="btn btn-success">Create Scorecard</button>
```